# datatables callback on pagination

Tags: ajax, datatable, switchery

I'm implementing [switchery](https://abpetkov.github.io/switchery/) into datatable in this way

**UPDATE**

```
  var table = $('#table').DataTable({
        pageLength: 25,
        responsive: true,
        deferRender: true,
        stateSave: false,
        info: false,
        ordering: false,
        dom: 'lTfgt<"float-left"i>p',
        ajax: {
            "url": "../src/routes.php",
            "type": "POST",
            "async":true,
            "dataType": "json",
            "data": function(d) {
                d.call = "data-vol";
                d.dataform = $('#filtroForm').serialize();
                d.market = JSON.stringify($('#jstree_topmarket').jstree("get_selected"));

                return d;
            }
        },
        language: {
            "url": "assets/js/plugins/dataTables/it_IT.txt"
        },
        "fnDrawCallback": function() {
            var elems = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.js-switch'));

            elems.forEach(function(html) {
                var switchery = new Switchery(html, { size: 'small' });
            });
        }
    });
```

and seems ok

[image]

but when I switch to page 2 and then come back to page 1, I have this result

[image]

**EDIT**

Replacing **fnDrawCallback** with **initComplete** seems not working

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using an [`initComplete`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete) function instead of `drawCallback`. This will avoid the problem you are seeing where you get new sliders added every time there is another draw event in your DataTable.

To access the checkbox nodes from `initComplete` you can use this:

```
"initComplete": function() {
  var allNodes = $('#example').DataTable().cells().nodes();
  $.each($( '.js-switch', allNodes), function(index, node) {
    var switchery = new Switchery(node, { size: 'small' });
  });   
}
```

The first line of the function uses the Datatables API to access every node in the table.

`allNodes` is a collection of `<td>` nodes - so then we have to select only those which contain a child node which uses your `js-switch` class.

Since we already have jQuery, I chose to use its iterator `$.each()` to iterate over al these checkbox nodes, to create the switchery object.

---

Update:

Here is the full DataTable I am using to test with:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
  data: dataSet,
  columns: [
    { title: "Name", data: "name" },
    { title: "Office", data: "office" },
    { title: "Position", data: "position" },
    { title: "", defaultContent: '<input type="checkbox" class="js-switch" checked />' }
  ],
  "initComplete": function() {
    var allNodes = $('#example').DataTable().cells().nodes();
    $.each($( '.js-switch', allNodes), function(index, node) {
      var switchery = new Switchery(node, { size: 'small' });
    }); 
  }

} );
```

My test data is in a JavaScript variable:

```
var dataSet = [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Tiger Nixon",
      "position": "System Architect",
      "salary": "$320,800",
      "start_date": "2011/04/25",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "5421"
    },

    // more data not shown here...

    {
      "id": "57",
      "name": "Donna Snider",
      "position": "Customer Support",
      "salary": "$112,000",
      "start_date": "2011/01/25",
      "office": "New York",
      "extn": "4226"
    }
  ];
```

Comment: Thanks but replacing fnDrawCallback with initComplete seems not working, i have native html checkbox

Comment: In my test, I am using checkboxes like this: `<input type="checkbox" class="js-switch" checked />`. They are placed in the related DataTable `<td></td>` cells. Can you describe what you mean by "not working"? What do you see? Are errors thrown in the browser's console? Do you still get multiple sliders in each cell?

Comment: I added my full test example, in case that helps.

Comment: Note that my DataTable is called "example" - yours may have a different name, as defined in the HTML table: `<table id="example"`...>...</table>`. You may need to change my code, accordingly.

Comment: I have also updated my first post with full code of datatable... Is it possibile the problem is the ajax call?

Comment: Did you change my example code to match your table name? Your table is called "table", whereas my table is called "example": `var allNodes = $('#table').DataTable().cells().nodes();`

Comment: Yes, now I'm using your sample code, but always works with with callback... And with your code, when I'm coming back from page 2 to 1, I'm seeing three switchery for each cell insted of 2... :)

Comment: OK - thank you for the notes. I do not know why your use of my code is behaving differently from my use of my code - very strange.

Comment: Thanks to you! Anyway I have also tried your full code and it works also with initComplete... Difference beetween yours and mine code, is ajax call, that I need ...

Answer (score 0):

I use `createdRow`, this is my code:

```
createdRow: function (row) {
    initializeSwitchElement(row)
}


function initializeSwitchElement(row) {
    let checkbox = Array.prototype.slice.call($(row).find('.js-switch'));
    if ($(checkbox).prop('checked')) {
        $(checkbox).trigger('keyup').blur()
    }
    checkbox.forEach(function (element) {
        new Switchery(element, { size: 'small' });
    });
}
```